# Url rewriting redirect 301 old to new website

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, url-rewriting

I have a problem with redirections from my old site to the new one.

**oldexample.com** is the old site, and **example.com** is the new site

- I would like to make sure that all my visitors are typing
  **oldexample.com** (all pages) are redirected to **example.com** which is the new site.
- If the user wants to access **oldexample.com/en/b2b** I would like it
  to remain on the domain **oldexample.com** and not be redirected to
  example.com.
- if the user arrives on **example.ch/** or **example.ch/fr** he is
  redirected to my new **example.com**
- if he reaches **example.ch/fr/b2b** that the user must be directed to
  the old site. **oldexample.com**

Here are my rules:

```
RewriteRule "fr/produits-fr/equilibre-et-vitalite-fr/ortie-fr" "https://exemple.swiss/products/ortie" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "fr/produits-fr" "https://sekoya.ch/collections/all" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "en/" "https://exemple.ch/a/l/en" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "de/" "https://exemple.ch/a/l/de" [R=301,L]
RewriteRule "fr/" "https://exemple.ch/a/l/de" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^fr/b2b
RewriteRule "(.*)" "https://www.exemple.ch/" [R=301,L]
```

But currently if I go to **example.com/fr/b2b** I come across the new site on the home page.
Where is the failure in my code.

Comment: I think you just need to add 
RewriteRule /fr/b2b https://oldsite.ch

Comment: I think you should first explain what sites you have where and where the problems are. I am not able to understand your question.

Comment: @MaxMuster I have the site oldexample.com
and example.com

I would like to make sure that all my visitors are typing oldexample.com (and all pages) are redirected to example.com which is the new site.
If the user wants to access oldexample.com/en/b2b I would like it to remain on the domain oldexample.com and not be redirected to example.com.
I have not yet made the b2b space of my new site and for now I would like to keep the one present on my old site.

Comment: @MaZoli Instead of my condition?

Comment: I tried to make your question more understandable.I still don't understand anything.
Please read it through again and decide which is the old domain and which is the new domain and list (as I did) what should be redirected to where.

Comment: @MaxMuster
Old domain abc.com ;
New domain: xyz.com ;
If the user wants to access abc.com he is directed to xyz.com ;
If the user wants to access any page from abc.com he is redirected to xyz.com ;
With the exception if the user wants to reach abc.com/fr/b2b he is redirected to abc.com/fr/b2b

Comment: You are juggling with the domains so that I get dizzy. Take a moment, have a tea, and write down the truth, which page should be redirected to which page.
Please do not obscure the URLs, there is no risk if you name the correct URLs here.
Furthermore, show us which rules have been written so far.
Do not write it in the comments, but update your question above. Write it systematically so that it is understandable for everyone.